# A unit test is intended to check for a particular failure, but it still fails even though the expected exception is thrown?

Tags: java, junit

I'm trying to write a unit-test to verify that it's impossible to create an instance of a certain object with a negative value.

My first test works OK as expected - it should pass.

My second test produces the IllegalArgumentException as expected, however the @Test(expected=IllegalArgumentException.class) does not absorb the error as I expected it to. In fact the test appears to behave exactly as if the @Test line were not there at all!

So what am I doing wrong?

```
package numbers;
import org.junit.Test;
import junit.framework.TestCase;
public class TestPositiveMoney extends TestCase {

    public void testConstructFromLong(  ) {
        // Works OK
        PositiveMoney x0 = new PositiveMoney( 3L );
    }

    @Test(expected=IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void testConstructInvalid( ) {
        // This statement is intended to fail
        PositiveMoney x0 = new PositiveMoney( -3L ); // Illegal
    }

}
```

FYI, the second test produces the following TB:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Negative value -3 not allowed
    at numbers.PositiveMoney.<init>(PositiveMoney.java:48)
    at numbers.TestPositiveMoney.testConstructInvalid(TestPositiveMoney.java:13)
```

Comment: You seem to be mixin juint 3 and 4 versions. Which runner do you use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `extends junit.framework.TestCase` is a JUnit 3 technique.
- `@Test(expected=IllegalArgumentException.class)` is for JUnit 4.

It seems you're using a test runner from JUnit 3. Try the following:

- add `@Test` to your first test
- drop `extends TestCase` clause

If it doesn't help—especially if the tests are not run any more—check what JUnit version you're using.
If you use maven, try `-X` command-line switch.

Comment: Got it! That fixed it. I also had to use the Junit4 test-runner in Eclipse and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: Anything `public void` having `@Test` annotation is a test. (The actual requirements can be more relaxed, but I haven't found a proper spec for that.)

Comment: You do not run into this kind of issues if you use [catch-exception](http://code.google.com/p/catch-exception/) which is independent of the testing framework.

Answer (score 3):

Which jUnit version do you use? 3 or 4? The @Test anntoation only works with jUnit 4.

When you use jUnit 4 you also don't need to extend your class from junit.framework.TestCase.

Comment: or name your methods `testFoo()`, for that matter.

Answer (score 1):

Annotate your class with `@RunWith(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` or don't extend `TestCase`